# Invoking a lambda function using localstack and docker container within ecr fails with a timeout

Tags: docker, .net-core, aws-lambda, localstack

Im trying to use local stack 0.14.3 and docker containers to execute lambda functions. I created a repository and pushed the code into a container.

```
awslocal ecr create-repository --repository-name calculation;
$existing_repository_uri=$(awslocal ecr describe-repositories --repository-names calculation --query "repositories[0].repositoryUri" --output text)
$existing_repository_uri
cd C:\repos\AWSServerless1\AWSServerless1
docker build -t localhost:4510/calculation:latest .
docker push localhost:4510/calculation:latest
```

Then I create my function

```
awslocal lambda create-function `
--function-name calculation1 `
--package-type Image `
--handler AWSServerless1::AWSServerless1.Functions::GetCalculation `
--runtime dotnetcore3.1 `
--code ImageUri=localhost:4510/calculation:latest `
--role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-dotnet-ex
```

When I try to invoke the function,using CLI or postman ( http://localhost:4566/2015-03-31/functions/calculation1/invocations) , I get the below error. I tried increasing the timeout of the function to 20 but I get the same error ( times out after 20 secs instead of 3)

```json
{
    "errorMessage": "Timeout - Lambda container did not report result after 3 secs",
    "errorType": "InvocationException",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_api.py\", line 533, in run_lambda\n    result = LAMBDA_EXECUTOR.execute(\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 466, in execute\n    return do_execute()\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 456, in do_execute\n    return _run(func_arn=func_arn)\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py\", line 170, in wrapped\n    raise e\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py\", line 166, in wrapped\n    result = func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 443, in _run\n    raise e\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 439, in _run\n    result = self._execute(lambda_function, inv_context)\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 762, in _execute\n    result = self.run_lambda_executor(lambda_function=lambda_function, inv_context=inv_context)\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/localstack_ext/services/awslambda/lambda_extended.py.enc\", line 608, in run_lambda_executor\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/localstack_ext/services/awslambda/lambda_extended.py.enc\", line 504, in run_lambda_executor\n",
        "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/localstack_ext/services/awslambda/lambda_extended.py.enc\", line 529, in do_run_lambda_executor\n"
    ]
}
```

Here is my doker compose file

```yaml
version: "3.8" 
services: 
   localstack: 
        image: localstack/localstack:latest
        container_name: localstack_test         
        privileged: true 
        ports: 
            - 53:53
            - 4510-4599:4510-4599            
            - 8000:8080
        environment: 
           - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=xxx
           - SERVICES=s3,sqs,dynamodb,lambda,cloudformation,ssm,iam,cloudwatch,sts,kinesis,events,xray,ecr           
           - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data     
           - LEGACY_PERSISTENCE=false
           - EDGE_PORT=4566 
           - PORT_WEB_UI=8081 
           - START_WEB=1
           - DEBUG=1 
           - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
           - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=true   
           - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localhost
           - LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME=localhost
           - REQUIRE_PRO=0               
        volumes: 
           - c:/localstack:/tmp/localstack 
           - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'  
        networks: 
            - localstack-ent 
networks: 
    localstack-ent: 
        external: false 
        driver: bridge
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same issue with ecr, did you ever figure out the solution to this?


My function was working fine when it didnt use ECR but requirements changed so it had to be included and now it fails when copying files across buckets, the file is in the new bucket but the timeout occurs

Comment: Haven't figured this out, sorry. We are just using zip files instead.